# Neither ViewBag nor ViewData appear in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After adding `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"` to `project.json` for an ASP.NET Core project, I created an Index.cshtml for a first view.

I tried to add `ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"` but `ViewBag` doesn't appear.

So answers recommended using `ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page"` but now `ViewData` doesn't appear either.

Well, what other object are we supposed to use now for Core 1.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, this issue has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core or MVC 1.0.0.

My VS 2015's ReSharper Ultimate was outdated. I promptly updated it and now all is well.